# tailwind css not changing the webpage

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, tailwind-css

I wan to to use the tailwind css framework for the first time, I tried to follow the tutorial on their page as close as possible, but it is not making any changes to my webpage and I don't know why.
Since I am very inexperieneced, I guess I have missed installing or doing something, since it is my first time using a framework for my project.
Also I have started using Visual Studio Code for my first time and I am a bit overwhelmed how everything works.

What I have got for now:

Installed node.js, since I read somewhere I need it for tailwind css, seems to work ***node --version*** command sends result.

Installed tailwind css in my project folder (project folder is inside HTDOCS folder from XAMPP) with  ***npx tailwindcss init*** in the vs terminal, after changing directories to my project folder.
Now I also have a node_modules folder and a tailwind.config.js there

Addet

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
```

in my home.html  and

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

to my style.css

Then I tried to add

```
class="bg-green-500"
```

to my body in home.html and it is shown in the editor, but not on the website...

What am I missing ?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you created tailwind.config.js file ?

Comment: It was aout generated, I only added the directories to the purge part:

module.exports = {
  purge: [
    './home.html',
    './code.js',

  ],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}

Comment: You need the liveserver plugin so you can have your site auto-refresh, its the easiest way. If you don't want to do that though and you still want to continue using XAMP you have to change ***ALL*** your paths to a relative path, for example `href="style.css"` to `href="/style.css"`

Comment: Thank you really much, at least that helped to get the normal css working, tailwind still isn't working though.

Comment: try running the `npx` command `npx tailwindcss -o tailwind.css
`
this will create a tailwind build file with all the classes.
But most probably intellisense would work.

Answer (score 2):

You should follow the official setup guide: [Get started with Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation)

From your description, you might have not followed the build step:

> Run the CLI tool to scan your template files for classes and build your CSS: `npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch`

Comment: I think this command have to be run in CLI the whole time we are developing with Tailwind. As a front-end newbie, this is new to me.